# Show Delphi And C++ Source Code

Tags: c++, delphi, decompiling

How can I see the source code of an executable compiled by Delphi or C++?

Please help me.

**After Edit:**

I have a program. When I start this program, it shows a dialog and asks for a password. This password is saved in source code. I want to take this password quickly and easily.

Comment: Is the password an English word? Then it is probably easily identified using a hex editor. Give me the EXE and I'll give it a try.

Comment: @hosseinsinohe Sounds to me like you want to hack into someone else software, huh? We are not at hackersguide.com or so.

Comment: @InsertNickHere Yes.But I want Help to Decompile an Assembly...

Comment: If you cannot tell what produced your 'executive' you have a long road ahead of you...

Comment: Decompiling an executable to get sourcecode is a bit like pushing shit down a cow's arse to make it spit fresh grass. Some processes are just irreversible.

Comment: If all you're wanting to do is crack the password that the app is expecting, you could scan for the password string in the exe file, assuming that it is not obscured.  If it is obscured or encrypted, you could run the app in a debugger with a CPU view and surf the machine code to find where the input text is compared against the internal value.  This is not easy and requires a fair amount of experience with machine code and low level app architecture. If you're going to go to that much trouble, you might as well just use the debugger to jump over the password compare and continue running.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't.

An enormous amount of information is thrown away when the compiler reduces human readable text source code down to machine executable code.  Local variables don't need names in machine code, for example, they're just register bits in the instruction opcode.

This is why debugging a compiled executable to step through the original source files line by line can only be done if you have the compiler debug symbols to go with the executable.

There are utilities that attempt to reverse engineer machine code into source code, but the result is less readable to humans than the original machine code, in my opinion.  Machine generated function names, machine generated local variables and arguments, and many times the utility has to guess as to the exact data types of arguments and local vars. (is this arg a signed int or an unsigned int?  Hard to tell when it's just a stack slot or machine register)

Compiling to an intermediate representation, as is done in Java and .NET, provides for much more reversibility because the types and symbol names of much of the original code are retained.  Reflector, for example, can emit C# source code that is very close to the original human written source code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  The compiler takes the source code and turns it into machine instructions leaving 'no trace' of the original source code behind.

There are programs called de-compilers, but they just basically automate reverse-engineering, they can't actually access the original source code because that's long gone.

Answer (score 1):

by using a disassembler or decompiler.  You can't ever get the original source code back from a binary though.  That information is lost.

Answer (score 1):

> How Can I See a Source Code of Executive File Compiled By Delphi or C++?

You can't, because source code does not exist in compiled Delphi/C++ program.

> I Have a Program.When I Start This Program,Show a Dialog And Ask a Password.This Password Saved in Source Code.I Want take This Password Quickly And Easily.

Trying to crack something, huh?
It is quite possible that password is not saved in source code. [Hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) can be used on a password to check if it is valid *without* storing password in a source code. Even if you find a hash, it won't be easy to get a password from it.

You can get an assembler listing from program using a disassembler (Ida Pro, OllyDBG, or similar tool). And you could debug your program even without source code, although you'll see pure assembly. AFAIK, "decompilers" exist, but I haven't ever used one of them, and doubt that they will be useful for C++/Delphi code (the one that compiles into native application).

There are a few simple techniques that would allow to hack program and bypass password check (if some conditions are met, program author wasn't into security, protection is easy, etc), but I'm not sure if this is allowed discussion topic on stackoverflow.

Anyway, if you're interested in reverse engineering for legal purposes, you could try a book called "Reversing: Secrets of Reverse Engineering".

Answer (score 0):

When you say "executive" do you mean "executable"? If so, decompiling will only get you assembly. Some decompilers will try to turn the assembly into a more readable form, but there's no general way to get the source code from an exe unless you actually compile the source code into the file.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the password is not saved in the source code.  The compilation process is one-way only; the finished product isn't going to go altering its source.  (Or its binary, for that matter, in most cases at least.)  The password is most likely saved in a data file someplace.  And if the program's author is at all competent, the password is hashed or encrypted in some way.  Decompiling the program won't help you much.

Also, as InsertNickHere mentioned, we're not a hacking site here.  We're honorable coders helping each other out with the complexities involved in building legitimate software.  Please take your shady questions elsewhere.